# How to go back from google play to my app

Tags: android

I want to call one app from another and if the app is not installed on device mean i get the control to google play store to install the app(these things are going well).But once download finished,i want to remove the googleplay activity and get back the control to my app.how will i do this one?thanks in advance....

Comment: you cannot. it is not your application, you cannot close it.

Answer (score 1):

Once the application is installed, the user would press the device's BACK button, to return to previous activity, to your app.

And I don't believe there's something you can trigger automatically return to your app, after application installment from Google Play.